# Signal routing to power amp LM1876 based on TS5A22362 SPDT

Tags: audio, routing, power-amplifier, preamp, spdt

Has anyone ever used the TI's TS5A22362 CI to route audio? I though of implementing the circuit below on which I intend to use the same supply voltage to switch between normally closed and normally closed pins, from a ceramic cartridge preamp and a RIAA one, to a LM1876 power amp. Will it work? Any dos and don'ts abut my circuit? What I want is: COM1 and COM2 straight to LM1876, NC1 = COM1 and NO2 = COM2, upon applying a voltage to IN2 and then, NO1 = COM1 and NC2 = COM2 upon appolying a voltage to IN2, and in both case what is connected to the four inputs, NC1/2 and NO1/2 are audio signals from a RIAA pre amp and from a ceramic cartridge pre amp, as shown on the image.

[image]

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a22362.pdf?ts=1611247159628&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTS5A22362

Comment: It's mislabeled I 1st thought of the TS5A22364, which seems to be incompatible with what I want then the TS5A22362 came to my knowledge and both have the same pinout. So, please disconsider the handwritten name.

Comment: I would highly recommend posting a schematic that isn't hand drawn to get better answers, not too many people are going to try to read this.